# Exibir o ano e mês que está vindo do array

Tags: php

Já consigo exibir o ano dentro do foreach pela posição, como eu faço pra exibir o mês também?

O array está vindo assim, o mês no caso seria aquele 3, 2, 3, 4 queria exibir esse valor dentro do meu foreach (esse é o var_dump na variavel arquivos)

```
    array (size=2)
  2016 => 
    array (size=1)
      3 => 
        array (size=1)
          2 => 
            object(stdClass)[44]
              ...
  2017 => 
    array (size=3)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          1 => 
            object(stdClass)[45]
              ...
      3 => 
        array (size=1)
          3 => 
            object(stdClass)[46]
              ...
      4 => 
        array (size=1)
          2 => 
            object(stdClass)[47]
              ...
```

Esse é o meu foreach, como eu poderia fazer isso?

```
<ul class="blogcat">
                        <?php foreach ($arquivos as $k => $a): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><?= $k; ?></a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#"><?= 'exibir o mes' ?></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você tem é uma matriz, um array multi-dimensional.

Para resolver essa questão você vai precisar aninhar um foreach dentro de outro. Seria basicamente isso:

```
<ul class="blogcat">
    <?php foreach ($arquivos as $indice1 => $valor1): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><?= $indice1; ?></a>
            <ul>
                <?php foreach ($valor1 as $indice2 => $valor2): ?>
                    <li><a href="#"><?= $indice2; ?></a></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Caso tenha intenção de exibir os dias também, basta seguir o mesmo raciocínio.

Comment: Puts é mesmo, precisava de outro foreach tinha me esquecido! Valeu Pedro funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: Valeu! Fico feliz que tenha lhe ajudado.